# Can't call EWS service with API Java SSL and certificates

Tags: java, calendar, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I am actually working on EWS Java API. The goal is to access data in the Calendar. So I started learning how to use the EWS Java API.

Begining with a sample example, I found some problems :

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
        ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("me@company.com",  "password");    
        service.setCredentials(credentials);            
        //WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy("proxy.domain.company", 8080);
        //There's no credentials for the proxy 
        //service.setWebProxy(webProxy);  
        try {
            service.setUrl(new URI("https://domain.company/ews/exchange.asmx"));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
        EmailMessage msg;
        try {
            msg = new EmailMessage(service);
            msg.setSubject("hello world");
            msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("Sent using the EWS API"));
            msg.getToRecipients().add("my.boss@company.com");
            msg.send();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Executing the code gave me at first errors related to dependencies at first then to certifications and SSL at a second time and here's a trace of the console :

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Building ol-v01 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ ol-v01 ---
    microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The request failed. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequestBase.int...
    Caused by: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    ....
    ... 38 more
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BUILD SUCCESS
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Total time: 7.891s
    Finished at: Tue Jun 09 17:49:04 CEST 2015
    Final Memory: 5M/119M
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Si I am trying to sove this issue :

I found some questions with the same problem, and I followed the steps to install the certifcate downloaded from the browser with keytool under `JAVA_HOME\lib\security\cacerts`

And I added it to with the `mmc.exe` tool under Third party Certificate Authorities.

So I can see that the installed certificate

Is there any way to solve this? is there a step that I didn't proceed? also I want to know if EWS let me to disable SSL checking?

NB : The server is the Entreprise Exchange 2010 SP2, so I will use my account to test, also I installed a local server on VM to see the difference and the problems because I have some problems with the proxy.

Also, I want to know if the administrator of the Server needs to activate something to use the EWS ?

Thanks for your help.

## Update 2

Here's the results after installing my own Exchange 2010 server on MS Server 2012 VM.

I can access OWA via https://192.168.1.59/owa/

As followed in some questions and tutorials, I exported the certificate from browser to a file. The name is `verifyfail.WIN-NS09AI4QBB8` and the CN = verifyfail.WIN-NS09AI4QBB8

I don't know why this name but it's ok.

The filename is verifyfail.WIN-NS09AI4QBB8.cer

Then I used the keytool to add this certificate to JAVA_HOME\lib\security\cacerts. I used as alias `verifyfail.WIN-NS09AI4QBB8`.

Also I added it to with the mmc.exe tool under Third party Certificate Authorities.

The code bcomes like this :

```
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("ab@domain.com",  "P@ssw0rd");
    service.setCredentials(credentials);                 
    try {
        service.setUrl(new URI("https://192.168.1.59/ews/exchange.asmx"));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    EmailMessage msg;
    try {
        msg = new EmailMessage(service);
        msg.setSubject("hello world");
        msg.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("Sent using the EWS API"));
        msg.getToRecipients().add("pp@domain.com");
        msg.send();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My POM file contains these dependencies :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.ews-java-api</groupId>
        <artifactId>ews-java-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

As output, I got this error : `The request failed. The request failed. Host name '192.168.1.59' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=WIN-NS09AI4QBB8)`

And the trace of execution :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building ol-v01 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ ol-v01 ---
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The request failed. Host name '192.168.1.59' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=WIN-NS09AI4QBB8)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:74)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:158)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.internalCreateItems(ExchangeService.java:594)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.createItem(ExchangeService.java:653)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Item.internalCreate(Item.java:245)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.EmailMessage.internalSend(EmailMessage.java:147)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.EmailMessage.send(EmailMessage.java:258)
    at com.soprahr.ol.v01.T10.testMethod(T10.java:46)
    at com.soprahr.ol.v01.T10.main(T10.java:24)
Caused by: microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. Host name '192.168.1.59' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=WIN-NS09AI4QBB8)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.getEwsHttpWebResponse(ServiceRequestBase.java:729)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(ServiceRequestBase.java:639)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:62)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name '192.168.1.59' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=WIN-NS09AI4QBB8)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:465)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:395)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.java:338)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.HttpClientWebRequest.executeRequest(HttpClientWebRequest.java:292)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.getEwsHttpWebResponse(ServiceRequestBase.java:720)
    ... 10 more
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2.145s
Finished at: Wed Jun 10 04:34:14 CEST 2015
Final Memory: 5M/119M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Update 3

In the detail tab of the certificate, the Oject Key has as value CN = verifyfail.WIN-NS09AI4QBB8 which is different to CN=WIN-NS09AI4QBB8

The certificate that I download using the browser contains verifyfail.WIN-NS09AI4QBB8.

In this case, what should I do to avoid this problem ?

[image]

Comment: The error is not related to EWS API directly, the server certificate is not found in your truststore, take a look at this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore

Comment: I follwed the solution in the link. I can see the alias of the certificate in the list using the keystore -list command, but the error persists ...

Answer (score 1):

The error is related to a DNS problem or a problem with the name in the server certificate.

Make sure that the name in the `CN attribute` of the certificate (WIN-NS09AI4QBB8) is resolvable and returns the correct IP address (192.168.1.59).

The name in the CN attribute value must resolve in DNS to the IP address of the server. The error message

```
The request failed. The request failed. Host name '192.168.1.59' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=WIN-NS09AI4QBB8)
```

occurs because the DNS name can not be resolved, or resolves to a wrong IP.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem.
I have download my certificate and imported this into keystore.
Whithin my code i say:

```
    systemProps.put(
            "javax.net.ssl.trustStore",
            "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
        );

    systemProps.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit");



    System.setProperties(systemProps);
```

When i set url manualy: i get this error:

> ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The request failed. The
>   remote server returned an error: (401)Unauthorized

And when i use autodiscover, i cant find any endpoints:

> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   Determining which endpoints are enabled for host mycompany.com
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   Host returned enabled endpoint flags: [Legacy]
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   No Autodiscover endpoints are available  for host mycompany.com

Answer (score 0):

in the url, do not use ip, insteaded by hostname,eg. https://172.50.1.73/owa, insteaded by https://exchange/owa, at here you should write the mapping relation to the hosts file, eg. 172.50.1.73  exchange;

Answer (score -1):

I have manually downloaded cerificate and imported it into my keystore using command : keytool -importcert -file nameofCertificate.(crt|cert) -keystore key
store.jks -alias "EWScert" 
then i added this command to my code
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",CERTIFICATION_FILE);
CERTIFICATION_FILE is path to to your cert file for me it is located in C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\lib\security\cacerts

and all this steps solved my problem